# Nodejs/Mongoose fail to compare documents

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongoose

I want to take each element of an array of documents I queried and check if it is in an other array of documents I queried

I have this model :

```
var dataTypeSchema = new Schema({

    name : String,
    description : String, 
    // Personnel || Professionel || Intime
    category : String,

    provenance : {
        type : Schema.ObjectId, 
        ref : 'Service'
    }

});
```

and this one :

```
var dataUseSchema = new Schema({
    purpose : {
        type : Schema.ObjectId, 
        ref : 'Purposes'
    },

    dataTypes : [{
        type : Schema.ObjectId, 
        ref : 'DataType'
    }],
    description : String,
    service : {
        type : Schema.ObjectId, 
        ref : 'Service'
    },
    user : {
        type : Schema.ObjectId, 
        ref : 'User'
    }
});
```

I basically query an array of dataTypes and then want to check for each one if it is in a specific dataUse.data

I tried several methods of comparison : includes, indexOf, even comparing each elements _ids, it always returns false

I have checked that both arrays indeed contain documents and that they have some documents in common

Here is my code (one attempt) for comparing, I am first getting an array of DataUses and then for each one I want to check which values it shares with the dataTypesArray

```
const dataTypesArray = await Service.getServiceDataTypes(req.params.serviceName)


DataUse.find({service : serviceID, user : serviceID})
.populate('purpose dataTypes service user')
.exec()
.then(dataUses => {
    for(let j = 0; j < dataUses.length; j++) {
        for(let k = 0; k < dataTypesIDs.length; k++) {
            if(dataUses[j].dataTypes.indexOf(dataTypesIDs[k])==-1) {
                dataUses[j]["otherData"].push(dataTypesIDs[k])
            }
        }

    }
    return dataUseArray
})
.catch(console.log)
```

For the last `if (condition)`, everything sets equal to -1
Both `dataTypes` arrays are populated, but as I said I tried comparing just *_id* and still same result

thanks !

Comment: I have improved your code, posting answer as well.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan thanks a lot for the improvement, do you know where the problem of comparison comes from?

Comment: In javascript you can't compare objects like `{} === {} // false`

Comment: @AlexandruOlaru how can you compare them then? i have tried just comparing the _ids, doesnt work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do it...

To compare an array with other of Mongoose Array.
See the IDs your are getting are `mongoose` `ObjectID` which is an *object*

To compare an **Array** of **ObjectID** with other **ObjectID**:

```
// converting dataTypes to String, 
// you can also convert it by using `lean`
// i.e  Model.find().lean().exec() 
// this would return JavascriptObject instead of MongooseModel

dataTypeIDs = dataTypes.map(i => i.toString()); // converting to plain 
// Array of string
dataTypeIDs.indexOf(someDataTypeID.toString()); // returns -1 if not found
```

You can use the last line to convert it anyway you like in your `if (condition)`

Change this block of code like this:

```
.then(dataUses => {
    // assuming its an Array of ObjectID
    dataTypesIDsArray = dataTypesIDs.map(i => i.toString())
    for(let j = 0; j < dataUses.length; j++) {
        usesDataTypes = dataUses[j].dataTypes.map(i => i.toString()) 
        for(let k = 0; k < dataTypesIDsArray.length; k++) {
            if(usesDataTypes.indexOf(dataTypesIDsArray[k]) == -1) {
                dataUses[j]["otherData"].push(dataTypesIDsArray[k])
                // use ObjectID from mongoDB if you want to cast it to "ObjectId"
            }
        }
    }
    return dataUseArray;
})
```

Its not tested, but I have taken reference of an existing tested code from my project.

Comment: thanks a lot this is of great help, I get it now, im sure it will work, testing it right away